# p:dataTable row missing some cells after editing

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

My primefaces datatable looks very similar to the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml), but it has a problem that in edit modus by either clicking cancel or ok, some cells are not shown. see the following code and this snapshot:

[image: edit mode]

[image: after clicking cancel or ok]

```
<h:form id="form1">
<p:dataTable  id="table1" var="table1" value="#{myHandler.datarows}" editable="true"
         rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
        filteredValue="#{myHandler.filteredDatarows}"
         style="margin: auto; width: 100%; border: 1; cellpadding: 3;"
         paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
         rows="12"
         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
         currentPageReportTemplate="&#8250;&#8250; {startRecord} - {endRecord} of {totalRecords} Rules">
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{myHandler.onEdit}" update=":form1:table1"/>
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"  listener="#{myHandler.onCancel}" update=":form1:table1"/>

<p:column headerText="Column1" style="width:10%" sortBy="#{datarow.column1}">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{datarow.column1}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText id="column1InputText" value="#{datarow.column1}" style="width:100%"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>

.....

<p:column style="width:6%">
    <p:rowEditor/>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Refreshing the page with F5 redraws the table correctly.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1

Comment: Is your backing bean at least `@ViewScoped`?

Comment: It is @SessionScoped

Comment: Your `p:ajax`es don't have `update` attribute. Try adding them.

Comment: I tried using update=":form1:table1". but it did not help.

Comment: always post an [mcve]